How are quantum states of particles represented in particle processes?
For example, lets say we have an electron-positron annihilation scenario. What will be the density matrix representing the quantum state of the electron and the positron? What will be the density matrix of the photons?

You are asking for infinite-dimensional Fock-space density matrices for QFT? Are you dissatisfied with the mainstream formulation of it?

I have not studied QFT. I am just reading Introduction to Elementary Particle Physics by Griffiths.

States used in QFT are usually rather simple: pure states represented as tensor products of single particles with fixed momenta and spin. The reason is that QFT is used for studying fundamental dynamics and not exotic states and their applications.

A single particle with definite spin $s$ and momentum $\vec p$ in QFT is described by the action of a creation operator on the vacuum:
$$
\vert\vec p,s\rangle = a^{s\dagger}_\vec p\vert \Omega\rangle
$$
Now this object lives in an infinite-dimensional space called the Fock space, which is the appropriate setting for relativistic many-body quantum mechanics. While it is a vector in the purely mathematical sense, it cannot be written as a tuple of numbers in a meaningful way, and likewise the outer product
$$
\vert\vec p,s\rangle\langle\vec p,s\vert$$
does not have a clear interpretation as a matrix. I have also never seen it used in this way. There is a close analog in terms of Dirac spinors however, which also represent single particles of spin $1/2$ and a certain momentum, and can be written as tuples in a meaningful way: If you consider the spinor $u_s(\vec p)\in\Bbb C^4$ where now $s = \pm 1/2$, one can form the object
$$
\sum_s u_s(\vec p)\bar{u}_s(\vec p) = p_\mu\gamma^\mu -m
$$
which does act as a projector in much the same way that a density matrix would.
